# Destroying session after logging out

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, logout

I'm using JavaScript, Angular and Java on my application. I need help with developing a logout operation that destroys a session. For now, on the logout link I'm calling the login page that's how when the BACK Button on the browser is clicked the user is still logged in.

`<li><a href="login.html">Log Out</a></li>`

Comment: And what's exactly your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269168/how-to-remove-single-object-from-the-sessionstorage-angularjs

Comment: are you creating a session using a post call ?

Comment: @MiteshPant Yes, I'm using a post call.

Comment: is there a delete available on that api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us say tat you are using  /sessions api to create session. let the response of the session be an id as

```
{id : ghjdgsajdfsgafdfdgasfdafsdfsafdjsa}
```

you can now store this id in session storage as

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentSession', response.id);
```

now on logout you can do the send the delete call on

```
/sessions/window.sessionStorage.getItem('currentSession');
```

This will destroy the session

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the state from HTML **:**

```
<li><a href="login.html">Log Out</a></li>
```

try something like this **:**

```
<li><a ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
```

Suppose you already set key(userid) & value(dynamic) in session storage on successful login

```
storageService.setItem('userid','1');
```

Now, on logout you can do something like this :

**Controller :**

```
$scope.logout = function() {

  // To remove specify key/value pair from session storage, you need to do something like this.
  storageService.removeItem('userid');

  // Redirection on home page after remove the item from session storage.
  $state.go('home'); 
     ----  OR -----
  $location.path('/home');

}
```

**`storageService` factory :**

```
app.factory('storageService', function () {

    return {

        getItem: function (key) {
            return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        },

        setItem: function (key,data) {
            sessionStorage.setItem(key, data);
        },

        removeItem: function (key) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem(key);
        }
    };
});
```